# Android Chrome Skip "Use saved passkey" screen

Tags: android, google-chrome, webauthn

My web app registers a user's biometric identity using the WebAuthn framework. When performing the challenge, Android Chrome first displays a "User saved passkey" screen. This creates an unnecessary additional screen that requires an extra click to get to the actual challenge. Is it possible to skip/bypass this screen somehow?

[image: Example "Use saved passkey" screen]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a step up / reauth scenario (e.g. you already know who the user is), you can send an allowCredentials list with the known credential IDs and transports.